# myElement.textContent is inconsistently displaying

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to call a function to validate email input using the blur event on two password inputs with different id's.

It displays my error message if I am clicking from a password input to the email input.  However, if I click from one password input to the other, my error message does not display.  It does registers the console.log message that is immediately below the error message, so the validation is occurring, but the error message is not displaying.

```js
 document.forms.myCreateAcctForm.noValidate = true;

      var myCreateAcctForm = document.getElementById('myCreateAcctForm');

      var myEmailTxtBox = document.getElementById('myEmailTxtBox');  
      var myPasswordTxtBox1 = document.getElementById('myPasswordTxtBox1');
      var myPasswordTxtBox2 = document.getElementById('myPasswordTxtBox2');

      var myCreateNewAcctBtn = document.getElementById('myCreateNewAcctBtn');
      var myClearNewAcctBtn = document.getElementById('myClearNewAcctBtn');

      var myEmailErrSpan = document.getElementById('myEmailErrSpan');
      var myPassword1ErrSpan = document.getElementById('myPassword1ErrSpan');
      var myPassword2ErrSpan = document.getElementById('myPassword2ErrSpan');
      
      var myCreateAcctFormErrP = document.getElementById('myCreateAcctFormErrP');

      var myEmail;
      var myPassword1;
      var myPassword2;

      var myUsers = [];
      var myNumUsers = myUsers.length;

      function MyUser(myEmail, myPassword) 
      {
        this.myEmail = myEmail;
        this.myPassword = myPassword;
      }

      function isValidEmail()
      {
        myEmail = myEmailTxtBox.value;
        
        var isValidEmail = true;
        var myEmailRegExPattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
        
        myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "";
        myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "";
        
        if (myEmail === "")
        {
          isValidEmail = false;
          myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "Email is required";
        }
        else if (!myEmailRegExPattern.test(myEmail.toUpperCase()))
        {
          isValidEmail = false;
          myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "Invalid email format";
        }
        else
        {
          for (var index = 0; index < myUsers.length; index++)
          {
            if (myEmail === myUsers[index].myEmail)
            {
              isValidEmail = false;
              myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "Email has already been used";
              break;
            }
          }      
        }  
        return isValidEmail;
      }

      function isValidPassword()
      {
        myPassword1 = myPasswordTxtBox1.value;
        myPassword2 = myPasswordTxtBox2.value;

        var isValidPassword1 = true;
        var isValidPassword2 = true;
        var myPasswordRegExPattern = /^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?([^\w\s]|[_])).{8,}$/
        
        myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "";
        myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "";
        
        if (myPassword1 === "")
        {
          isValidPassword1 = false;
          myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "Password is required";
          console.log("password1 blank");  
        }  
        
        if (isValidPassword1 === true && !myPasswordRegExPattern.test(myPassword1))
        {
          isValidPassword1 = false;
          myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "Invalid password format";    
          console.log("password1 wrong format");  
        }
        
        if (myPassword2 === "")
        {
          isValidPassword2 = false;
          myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "Matching password is required";
          console.log("password2 blank");  
        }
        
        if (isValidPassword2 === true && !myPasswordRegExPattern.test(myPassword2))
        {
          isValidPassword2 = false;
          myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "Invalid password format";    
          console.log("password2 wrong format");  
        }
        
        if (isValidPassword1 === true && isValidPassword2 === true && myPassword1 !== myPassword2)
        {
          isValidPassword1 = false;
          isValidPassword2 = false;
          myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = 'Passwords must match';
          myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = 'Passwords must match';
          console.log("passwords not equal");  
        }
        return isValidPassword1 && isValidPassword2;
      }

      function isValidCreateAcctForm()
      {
        var isValidEmailBool = isValidEmail();
        var isValidPasswordBool = isValidPassword();
        
        myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "";
        
        if (isValidEmailBool && isValidPasswordBool)
        {
          createAccount();
        }
        else 
        {
          myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "Please fix errors and try again";
        }  
      }

      function createAccount()
      {
        var myUser = new MyUser(myEmail, myPassword1);
        myUsers.push(myUser);
      }

      function clearCreateAcctForm()
      {
        myEmailTxtBox.value = "";  
        myPasswordTxtBox1.value = "";
        myPasswordTxtBox2.value = "";
        
        myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "";
        myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "";
        myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "";

        myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "";
      }

      window.addEventListener('load', clearCreateAcctForm);

      myCreateAcctForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) 
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          isValidCreateAcctForm();
        }, false);

      myCreateAcctForm.addEventListener('reset', function (e) 
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          clearCreateAcctForm();
        }, false);

      window.addEventListener('focus', function(event)
        {
          myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "";
          
          switch (event.target.id)
          {
            case 'myEmailTxtBox':
              myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "";
              break;      
            case 'myPasswordTxtBox1':
              myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "";
              myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "";
              break;
            case 'myPasswordTxtBox2':
              myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "";
              myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "";
              break;      
          }
        }, true);

      window.addEventListener('blur', function(event)
        {
          switch (event.target.id)
          {
            case 'myEmailTxtBox':
              isValidEmail();
              break;      
            case 'myPasswordTxtBox1':
              isValidPassword();
              break;
            case 'myPasswordTxtBox2':
              isValidPassword();
              break;      
          }
        }, true);
```

```css
.myErrorMsg {
        color: #CC3422;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .myCreateAcctFormBody {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 9rem 12rem auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-row-gap: 1rem;
        grid-column-gap: 1rem;
      }
```

```html
    <form name="myCreateAcctForm" id="myCreateAcctForm">
      <div class="myCreateAcctFormBody">
        <label for="myEmailTxtBox">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="myEmailTxtBox" id="myEmailTxtBox">
        <span id="myEmailErrSpan" class="myErrorMsg"></span>
        
        <label for="myPasswordTxtBox1">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="myPasswordTxtBox1" id="myPasswordTxtBox1">
        <span id="myPassword1ErrSpan" class="myErrorMsg"></span>
        
        <label for="myPasswordTxtBox2">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="myPasswordTxtBox2" id="myPasswordTxtBox2">
        <span id="myPassword2ErrSpan" class="myErrorMsg"></span>
      </div>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="myCreateNewAcctBtn">
      <input type="reset" id="myClearNewAcctBtn">    
      <p id="myCreateAcctFormErrP" class="myErrorMsg"></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code for us to sift through.

Comment: Looks like you clear both error message spans when either password field is focused. So if the first one has an error and you move to the second one, it clears the error on the first one as well as the second one. You need to break up your error handling routine between the two password fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing the strings from both password error spans when you focus on either.

Try writing it like this instead:

```
      switch (event.target.id)
      {
        case 'myEmailTxtBox':
          myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "";
          break;      
        case 'myPasswordTxtBox1':
          myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "";
          break;
        case 'myPasswordTxtBox2':
          myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "";
          break;      
      }
```

---

Example:

```js
document.forms.myCreateAcctForm.noValidate = true;

      var myCreateAcctForm = document.getElementById('myCreateAcctForm');

      var myEmailTxtBox = document.getElementById('myEmailTxtBox');  
      var myPasswordTxtBox1 = document.getElementById('myPasswordTxtBox1');
      var myPasswordTxtBox2 = document.getElementById('myPasswordTxtBox2');

      var myCreateNewAcctBtn = document.getElementById('myCreateNewAcctBtn');
      var myClearNewAcctBtn = document.getElementById('myClearNewAcctBtn');

      var myEmailErrSpan = document.getElementById('myEmailErrSpan');
      var myPassword1ErrSpan = document.getElementById('myPassword1ErrSpan');
      var myPassword2ErrSpan = document.getElementById('myPassword2ErrSpan');
      
      var myCreateAcctFormErrP = document.getElementById('myCreateAcctFormErrP');

      var myEmail;
      var myPassword1;
      var myPassword2;

      var myUsers = [];
      var myNumUsers = myUsers.length;

      function MyUser(myEmail, myPassword) 
      {
        this.myEmail = myEmail;
        this.myPassword = myPassword;
      }

      function isValidEmail()
      {
        myEmail = myEmailTxtBox.value;
        
        var isValidEmail = true;
        var myEmailRegExPattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
        
        myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "";
        myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "";
        
        if (myEmail === "")
        {
          isValidEmail = false;
          myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "Email is required";
        }
        else if (!myEmailRegExPattern.test(myEmail.toUpperCase()))
        {
          isValidEmail = false;
          myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "Invalid email format";
        }
        else
        {
          for (var index = 0; index < myUsers.length; index++)
          {
            if (myEmail === myUsers[index].myEmail)
            {
              isValidEmail = false;
              myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "Email has already been used";
              break;
            }
          }      
        }  
        return isValidEmail;
      }

      function isValidPassword()
      {
        myPassword1 = myPasswordTxtBox1.value;
        myPassword2 = myPasswordTxtBox2.value;

        var isValidPassword1 = true;
        var isValidPassword2 = true;
        var myPasswordRegExPattern = /^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?([^\w\s]|[_])).{8,}$/
        
        myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "";
        myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "";
        
        if (myPassword1 === "")
        {
          isValidPassword1 = false;
          myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "Password is required";
          console.log("password1 blank");  
        }  
        
        if (isValidPassword1 === true && !myPasswordRegExPattern.test(myPassword1))
        {
          isValidPassword1 = false;
          myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "Invalid password format";    
          console.log("password1 wrong format");  
        }
        
        if (myPassword2 === "")
        {
          isValidPassword2 = false;
          myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "Matching password is required";
          console.log("password2 blank");  
        }
        
        if (isValidPassword2 === true && !myPasswordRegExPattern.test(myPassword2))
        {
          isValidPassword2 = false;
          myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "Invalid password format";    
          console.log("password2 wrong format");  
        }
        
        if (isValidPassword1 === true && isValidPassword2 === true && myPassword1 !== myPassword2)
        {
          isValidPassword1 = false;
          isValidPassword2 = false;
          myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = 'Passwords must match';
          myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = 'Passwords must match';
          console.log("passwords not equal");  
        }
        return isValidPassword1 && isValidPassword2;
      }

      function isValidCreateAcctForm()
      {
        var isValidEmailBool = isValidEmail();
        var isValidPasswordBool = isValidPassword();
        
        myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "";
        
        if (isValidEmailBool && isValidPasswordBool)
        {
          createAccount();
        }
        else 
        {
          myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "Please fix errors and try again";
        }  
      }

      function createAccount()
      {
        var myUser = new MyUser(myEmail, myPassword1);
        myUsers.push(myUser);
      }

      function clearCreateAcctForm()
      {
        myEmailTxtBox.value = "";  
        myPasswordTxtBox1.value = "";
        myPasswordTxtBox2.value = "";
        
        myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "";
        myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "";
        myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "";

        myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "";
      }

      window.addEventListener('load', clearCreateAcctForm);

      myCreateAcctForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) 
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          isValidCreateAcctForm();
        }, false);

      myCreateAcctForm.addEventListener('reset', function (e) 
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          clearCreateAcctForm();
        }, false);

      window.addEventListener('focus', function(event)
        {
          myCreateAcctFormErrP.textContent = "";
          
          switch (event.target.id)
          {
            case 'myEmailTxtBox':
              myEmailErrSpan.textContent = "";
              break;      
            case 'myPasswordTxtBox1':
              myPassword1ErrSpan.textContent = "";
              break;
            case 'myPasswordTxtBox2':
              myPassword2ErrSpan.textContent = "";
              break;      
          }
        }, true);

      window.addEventListener('blur', function(event)
        {
          switch (event.target.id)
          {
            case 'myEmailTxtBox':
              isValidEmail();
              break;      
            case 'myPasswordTxtBox1':
              isValidPassword();
              break;
            case 'myPasswordTxtBox2':
              isValidPassword();
              break;      
          }
        }, true);
```

```css
.myErrorMsg {
        color: #CC3422;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .myCreateAcctFormBody {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 9rem 12rem auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-row-gap: 1rem;
        grid-column-gap: 1rem;
      }
```

```html
<form name="myCreateAcctForm" id="myCreateAcctForm">
      <div class="myCreateAcctFormBody">
        <label for="myEmailTxtBox">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="myEmailTxtBox" id="myEmailTxtBox">
        <span id="myEmailErrSpan" class="myErrorMsg"></span>
        
        <label for="myPasswordTxtBox1">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="myPasswordTxtBox1" id="myPasswordTxtBox1">
        <span id="myPassword1ErrSpan" class="myErrorMsg"></span>
        
        <label for="myPasswordTxtBox2">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="myPasswordTxtBox2" id="myPasswordTxtBox2">
        <span id="myPassword2ErrSpan" class="myErrorMsg"></span>
      </div>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="myCreateNewAcctBtn">
      <input type="reset" id="myClearNewAcctBtn">    
      <p id="myCreateAcctFormErrP" class="myErrorMsg"></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I totally overlooked that!